# HTML 5 page transitions

Tags: css, html

I want to make a nice, modern-looking transitions between pages. I've found this tutorial: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

The author uses JQuery to make it work, but I want to do it in pure HTML5. Is there a feature in HTML5 to do it, say, in CSS?

**UPDATE**

In the end of 2014, I'd like to add the following comment. Before doing it think twice, wouldn't it be better to make a single-page AJAX web-app with CSS3 transitions between DIVs. The question describes a very special situation which is extremely rare. In the rest 99% cases a single page app is the best solution.

Comment: I wonder if the transition property may be what you are looking for, but it is a css3 solution.  You could try it on the body element. http://www.cardeo.ca/2010/creating-a-fading-link-transition-with-css3

Comment: this is not an answer to your question, but I checked how this works and I wouldn't recommend it: The fade-out just delays the time the new page takes to start loading and I don't see really anything remarkable about the effect.

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I understood, there are two states of a link: normal and hover, so we can set the styles for both states, as well as transitions parameters, and the rest is being done by the browser. But I have a button, changing window.location in onclick, and I'm out of ideas, how to make 2 states for body: loaded (normal) and loading (faded-out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

index.htm:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
body,html,iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; border: 0; }

#mainframe.normal
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#mainframe.faded
{
    opacity: 0.0;
}
#mainframe
{
        /* Firefox */
        -moz-transition-property: opacity;
        -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
        /* WebKit */
        -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
        /* Standard */
        transition-property: opacity;
        transition-duration: 3s;
}

</style>

<script language="javascript">
function change()
{
    document.getElementById('mainframe').className="faded";
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('mainframe').src='page2.htm';
        document.getElementById('mainframe').className="normal";
    }, (2 * 1000));
}
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
<iframe id="mainframe" class="normal" src="page1.htm"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

page1.htm

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: pink;">
Hi, I'm page1

<button onclick="parent.change();">
click me
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

page2.htm

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: pink;">
Hi, I'm page2
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is based on the correct answer posted above which helped me a lot. Unfortunately, it was not working for me in chrome/linux, it worked well in firefox. I was looking for something slightly different anyway, because I wanted a common header in all pages. So here is my adatped solution.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
body,html,iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; border: 0; }

#mainframe.normal
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#mainframe.faded
{
    opacity: 0.0;
}
#mainframe
{
        /* Firefox */
        -moz-transition-property: opacity;
        -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
        /* WebKit */
        -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
        /* Standard */
        transition-property: opacity;
        transition-duration: 3s;
}

</style>

<!--<script language="javascript">-->
<script>
function change(page)
{
//  document.write('Hello World');
    document.getElementById('mainframe').className="faded";
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('mainframe').src=page+'.html';
        document.getElementById('mainframe').className="normal";
    }, (2 * 1000));
}
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
    <header id="header">
        <h2 id="name">
            FRANCISCO</br>
            FRANCHETTI
        </h2>
        <nav id="pages">
            <ul id="list-nav">
                <li class="current"><a onclick="change('home')" href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="change('research')" href="#">RESEARCH</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="change('teaching')" href="#">TEACHING</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="change('contact')" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <iframe id="mainframe" class="normal" src="home.html"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Main Remarks:

- The pages do not need to have buttons or anything, here the handler
  is the header which is common to all pages.
- The `href` attributes are disabled because we don't want to really navigate, just
  repopulate the `src` for the `iframe`.
- Now the `change()` function takes a
  parameter `page` that is used to determine which page to load; as said before, instead
  of passing the destination for the `a` in the `href` attribute, we
  pass it as a function argument for `change()`.