# Possible to animate between separate pages with HTML5 or AJAX?

Tags: ajax, html

I have a site with about 10 pages. On each page its the same layout and just the image changes. Is it possible (EG with HTML or AJAX) to animate the image change when you navigate to a new page?

I want the appearance to be as close to a normal jQuery slider as possible:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php

I haven't used the Cycle 2 plugin as I need each page to have a separate URL. The Cycle 2 plug in does have bookmark-able slides but they use fragment identifiers for each 'page' which social media sharing widgets sometimes ignore. So mysite.com/#page3 is shared as mysite.com, meaning the first not third slide is linked to.

The social media sharing widgets also use meta data from the page which doesn't change per slide as its still the same page.

Comment: Google: css3 page transitions

Comment: What code have you already tried?  What errors did it give?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 page transitions, remain on one page and just manipulate the URL as you need to. See for example: [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good answer to your question using HTML5 Transitions:
[HTML 5 page transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332195/html-5-page-transitions)

Hope this helps!