# CSS Transition between nearly identical pages

Tags: html, css

I have two pages, index.html and about.html, both using the same CSS styling.

On my website, two of the links are About and Home. The only difference between these two pages is the paragraph text displayed (the nav and footer are identical).

How would I create a transition for the page/text when the about link is clicked from the home page or vice versa?

A default ease transition is what I'm looking for, and let's say I gave the paragraphs an id = "target"

In my css file, would I do something like

```
#target {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

I have no idea what css property I would need to specify.

Comment: do you have the possibility to put the paragraph texts in the same file?

Comment: If you're changing actual pages (URL) then there is no CSS transition that can help...you'd need JS.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332195/html-5-page-transitions

Comment: If I put them in the same file would there be a way to hide one paragraph and replace it with the other upon link?

Comment: @patrickstarpants - yes, you can easily do that with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will require some JavaScript or JQuery.

**HTML**

```
<a id="homeLink">Home</a>
<a id="aboutLink">About</a>

<p id="targetHome">This is the home Paragraph...</p>
<p id="targetAbout" class="hidden">This is the about Paragraph...</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", "#aboutLink", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the <a> element from redirecting
    $("#targetHome:visible").hide("fade", 300, function(){
       $("#targetAbout:hidden").show("fade", 300); //Show About Paragraph if hidden
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#homeLink", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the <a> element from redirecting
    $("#targetAbout:visible").hide("fade", 300, function(){
       $("#targetHome:hidden").show("fade", 300); //Show Home Paragraph if hidden
    });
});
```

Comment: Using this keeps both paragraphs displayed though, would the <a> not have a href? Using the code you typed for my js file, both paragraphs are displayed and the links don't work.

Comment: @patrickstarpants I added  the bootstrap hidden class to the about paragraph. There are no links in the <a> elements because they no longer redirect a user but instead act as "clickables" that toggle paragraph visibility. (Basically to take this answer the final step make sure the About Paragraph is hidden when the page loads.)